# Which C# compiler errors are undocumented?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

This is meant to be a collection of possible C# compiler errors that are not documented.

If you encounter such an error, please post an answer here listing:

- The error number (CS*nnnn*)
- The associated error message
- If possible, a small snippet of code that will produce the error

#### Example:

> ### CS0224:
>
> > A method with vararg cannot be generic, be in a generic type, or have a params parameter
>
> #### Produced by:
>
> ```
> int Foo<T>(__arglist) { return 0; }
> ```

If someone has already posted an answer listing the error you encountered, then edit that answer to add additional details.

[The list of *documented* errors can be found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296.aspx). There seem to be quite a few missing...

Comment: "Your search - **CS0224 site:msdn.microsoft.com** - did not match any documents." Interesting. Probably because `__arglist` is an unsupported keyword.

Comment: Exactly dtb, there are a bunch of missing others probably. Unfortunately it seems everyone was too thick to think for a moment.

Comment: There are quite a few CSxxxx missing from the MSDN documentation. The complete list of documented error codes is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure that all the gaps in the numbering represent real error messages.  Some, hopefully all but this one, are codes for errors that were deprecated during internal development and which are not producible with a released version of the compiler.

Comment: Re-written, re-opened. Seems like it could be a useful enough topic... 
**@Leppie:** I left CS0224 in as an example, but it might be more effective to move it into its own answer.

Comment: I just wonder what is the purpose of this. You just repeat what is already in the compiler error message. Do you need more info? Is something unclear in this error message? Do you disagree with it?

Comment: @Alexandra: just for information. I hit the error, instinctively hit F1 as I wanted more info, but no result. Google did not yield any results either. I guess I was the first person to ever get this error :)  At least now, someone can start a discussion on a specific error. Maybe it is useless, maybe it is not.

Comment: I don't think you were the first one who got it, but may be the first one who needed more info. In many cases, an error message is all a user needs. If you think that error message is hard to understand or if you think that it should have more information than can be presented in a short text message, than it is a different story. But I still don't see a point in simply repeating what the compiler said.
By the way, if you find an error message that you do not like and really want to be more descriptive, file a bug via Microsoft Connect. Error messages are product features same as UI labels.

Comment: @Alexandra: I am not sure why this is disturbing you. Is sharing knowledge and information that MS did not include in the documentation a problem for you (or MS for that matter)?

Comment: It's not "disturbing me". My team owns this set of error messages. If you think that something is missing or unclear, I'd like to know what it is and how we can improve the docs.

Comment: @Alexandra: as you're no doubt aware, MSDN provides, for topics that it hosts, a mechanism for users to attach comments, code snippets, workarounds, etc. 

However, such a thing is not possible for *topics that don't exist*. Therefore, this page might offer some value for folks who would otherwise be confused by the lack of information on these errors. Some of us rely heavily on Google before filing support tickets...

Answer (score 4):

Found in the compiler string resource table but not in the MSDN Library index.  Many of them are surely obsolete, some smell like interesting undocumented features like support for modules and testing.  Checked up to CS2000:

CS0018: Operator 'xxx' not yet implemented
CS0240: 'xxx' cannot be both abstract and sealed (now CS0418)
CS0679: Other languages may permit the internal virtual member 'xxx' to be overridden
CS0767: Cannot inherit interface 'xxx' with the specified type parameters because it causes method 'yyy' to contain overloads which differ only on ref and out
CS0846: An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments
CS0847: An expression tree may not contain an indexed property
CS0848: Indexed property 'xxx' has non-optional arguments which must be provided
CS0849: Indexed property 'xxx' must have all arguments optional
CS0850: Partial declarations of 'xxx' must have the same type parameter names and variance modifiers in the same order
CS0851: Using 'is' to test compatibility with 'dynamic' is essentially identical to testing compatibility with 'object' and will succeed for all non-null values
CS1114: Member 'yyy' on embedded interop type 'xxx' cannot be evaluated while debugging since it is never referenced in the program.  Consider casting the source object to type 'dynamic' first or building with the 'Embed Interop Types' property set to false when debugging
CS1543: Added module 'xxx' has unresolved reference to type 'yyy'
CS1544: Added module 'yyy' references module 'xxx' which was not added
CS1595: Delegate 'xxx' has some invalid arguments
CS1735: Ignoring /win32manifest for module because it only applies to assemblies
CS1736: Cannot convert 'xxx' to delegate because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
CS1737: Expected parameter
CS1738: Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been 
specified. Please use language version 7.2 or greater to allow non-trailing main arguments.

CS1739: Filename given with /appconfig is too long or invalid.  Re-purposed in Roslyn (C# v6) to: The best overload for 'M' does not have a parameter named 'x'.
CS1903: Unrecognized value 'xxx' provided for '/test' option
CS1904: 'xxx' is not a valid warning number

Answer (score 2):

**CS1669:**

__arglist is not valid in this context

**Produced by:**

```
delegate int Bar(__arglist);
```

Comment: I am not sure why this construct is not allowed. When crafting the intention in IL, this delegate can be consumed without issues in C#. (VS is another story).

Answer (score 2):

**CS0002:**

Unable to load message string from resources

**Produced by:**

Most likely due to damage to the string table resource or a completely missing cscui.dll so it can't display any error messages.  Reference question [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9854027/17034).

Answer (score 1):

More like Leppie's example, found in the compiler string resource table and presumably triggered by undocumented keywords:

CS0190: The __arglist construct is valid only within a variable argument method
CS0224: A method with vararg cannot be generic, be in a generic type, or have a parameter array
CS0257: An __arglist parameter must be the last parameter in a formal parameter list

Answer (score 0):

**CS1738:**

Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been 
specified. Please use language version 7.2 or greater to allow non-trailing main arguments.

**Produced by**

```
string str = GetNewString(isAllowed: isUserAllowed, str);
```

> **Potential Solution: Upgrade to C# version 7.2 or greater**
>
> Right-click on the project to upgrade --> Properties --> Build --> Advanced --> Language version.
>
> [image: Upgrade to latest minor version of C#]