# VS2010 compiles solution without errors, msbuild fails: "fatal error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, compiler-errors

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to track down the cause of this error message. I have a large Visual Studio 2010 solution which compiles without error on my local machine but on the build server, msbuild fails on one of the projects with the error:

**fatal error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources**

Here's the red error section at the end:

```
Build FAILED.

"C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\85eff164854b9e67\Libraries\Domainface.Proxy.Common\Domainface.Proxy.Common.csproj" (default target) (9) ->
(CoreCompile target) -> 
  CSC : fatal error CS0002: Unable to load message string from resources. [C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\85eff164854b9e67\Libraries\Domainface.Proxy.Common\Domainface.Proxy.Common.csproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

The entire msbuild output from the build server is here: http://pastie.org/3660842

What does the error generally refer to, that would cause it to build locally but not on the build server?

**UPDATE**

I have just run `msbuild /version` on both machines and it turns out the .net framework versions are very slightly different. Local machine is `4.0.30319.488` and build server is `4.0.30319.1`. I'm about to run windows update on the server to allow it to install some updates, as several seem to be .net framework-related, so I'll see if that makes a difference.

**UPDATE**

Installing the updates didn't help. Just remembered I copied up csc.exe from the async preview a little while ago in order to facilitate async compilation (the actual async preview had failed to install on the server due to visual studio not being there, but installing visual studio team viewer seems to have fixed that, so i've just run the proper async ctp3 installer to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Erm, wait, are you saying you managed to fool the CTP installer and now you are having hard to explain problems and you don't know why?

Comment: Well it seems to have done the trick. Apparently just overwriting csc.exe was a bad move which must have led to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CS0002 is not documented.  Interpreting the error message, I'd say that the compiler is trying to show you a compile error message but fails when it tries to retrieve the message text.  Slightly odd is that it doesn't actually have a string table in its resources, not sure where it comes from.

Well, something is pretty borken.  Your idea to update the .NET framework version is solid, that will update csc.exe as well.  Ought to be good enough to fix any damage.

Answer (score 0):

This is often a problem with [the Entity Framework designer's handling of your connection strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716717.aspx). In your app.config file, make sure the assembly and resource names are what they're supposed to be.

Here's the format for that particular part of the connection string:

```
Metadata= res://<assemblyFullName>/<resourceName>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on my own experience of trying to solve the problem, as well as Hans's answer and a few other discussions I dug up while Googling, I'm guessing that the only way to make this error occur is to have an issue with current state of one's .Net framework installation. Essentially, a mismatch between the compiler and some other resource it uses means when the compiler hits an error, it tries to pull the error message from the referenced resource, but because the resource doesn't match the compiler build, the error message is unavailable and instead the compiler reports that it can't load the message (and thus can't effectively display the correct error message).

Hence the fix is to repair the .Net framework installation, which can be done by reinstalling it, running a repair on it, or installing a newer version (which in my case was the async ctp, which while not a full .net framework version upgrade, was enough to correct any mismatched resource references used by the compiler).